# Query optimization to yield computational results

Tags: sql, query-optimization

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XijCM.png)
It is very difficult to add tables in this posting, atleast I dont know.  Tried using HTML table tags, but they wont appear good. Hence posting the table structure as an image.

Considering the 3 tables seen in the image, Projects, BC, Actual Spend, as an sample, I'm looking for an optimal query that returns the Reports as the result.  As you can see, BC has some computation, Actual Spend has

```
SELECT ProjectId, Name, Budget
        , (SELECT b.[BC]  FROM [BC] b
                WHERE b.[BC] IN 
                    (SELECT SUM(mx.[BC]) FROM [BC] mx
                        WHERE ProjectId=p.ProjectId)) AS 'BC'
        , (SELECT sp.[ActualSpendAmount] FROM [ActualSpend] sp
                WHERE sp.[DateSpent] IN 
                    (SELECT MAX(as.[DateSpent]) FROM [ActualSpend] as
                        WHERE ProjectId=p.ProjectId)) AS 'Actual Spend'

        , t.[Budget] - ((SELECT b.[BC]  FROM [BC] b
                            WHERE b.[BC] IN 
                                (SELECT SUM(mx.[BC]) FROM [BC] mx
                                    WHERE ProjectId=p.ProjectId)) 
                        + 
                        (SELECT sp.[ActualSpendAmount] FROM [ActualSpend] sp
                            WHERE sp.[DateSpent] IN 
                                (SELECT MAX(as.[DateSpent]) FROM [ActualSpend] as
                                    WHERE ProjectId=p.ProjectId)))

    FROM Projects p;
```

---

As you can see, the SELECT for BC, Actual Spend is run twice.  I have several other tables like BC, Actual Spend, that yields some computation.  Is there any way to optimize this.  Even if I put them in a function, it would be the same, the function would need to be called more than once. 
Is there a way to optimize this query.

---

Pasting the table structure below:

Projects Table:

```
ProjectId   Name    Budget                      
1   DeadRock    500000                      
2   HardRock    300000
```

BC Table:                   Actual Spend Table:

```
ProjectId   BCId    BC  ApprovalDate        ProjectId   ActualSpendId   ActualSpendAmount   DateSpent
1   1   5000    2015/02/01      1   1   "       15000"  "   2015/03/01"
1   2   3000    2015/03/10      1   2   "       33000"  "   2015/05/12"
1   3   15000   2015/05/01      1   3   "       45000"  "   2015/06/03"
1   4   5000    2015/07/01      1   4   "       75000"  "   2015/07/11"
2   5   2000    2015/03/19      2   5   "       5000"   "   2015/04/20"
2   6   6000    2015/05/20      2   6   "       19000"  "   2015/05/29"
2   7   25000   2015/08/01      2   7   "       42000"  "   2015/06/23"
                    2   8   "       85000"  "   2015/07/15"
```

Report:

```
ProjectId   Name    Budget  BC  Actual Spend    ETC         
"1      "   DeadRock    500,000 28,000  75,000  397,000 Budget-(BC+ActualSpend)     
"2      "   HardRock    300,000 "   33,000" 85,000  182,000 Budget-(BC+ActualSpend)
```

Comment: What's your DBMS? Looks like SQL Server, which version?

Answer (score 0):

Your correlated subquery for `BC` does not make any sense:

```
, (SELECT b.[BC]  FROM [BC] b
            WHERE b.[BC] IN 
                (SELECT SUM(mx.[BC]) FROM [BC] mx
                    WHERE ProjectId=p.ProjectId)) AS 'BC'
```

If we concentrate on projectID 1, you have the data here:

```
ProjectId   BCId    BC      ApprovalDate  
--------------------------------------------
1           1       5000    2015/02/01     
1           2       3000    2015/03/10      
1           3       15000   2015/05/01     
1           4       5000    2015/07/01
```

Therefore this part of the query:

```
                (SELECT SUM(mx.[BC]) FROM [BC] mx
                    WHERE ProjectId=p.ProjectId)
```

Will return 28,000. Then what you essentially have is:

```
, (SELECT b.[BC]  FROM [BC] b
            WHERE b.[BC] IN (28000)) AS 'BC'
```

Which will return null, unless there happens to be 1 and only 1 record in the table for any project with that particular amount in BC. If there is more than one you will get an error because more than one record is returned in the subquery.

I suspect, based on the report data you simply want the sum, so you can simply use:

```
SELECT  p.ProjectId, 
        p.Name, 
        p.Budget
        bc.BC
FROM    Projects p
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  bc.ProjectID, SUM(bc.BC) AS bc
            FROM    BC
            GROUP BY bc.ProjectID
        ) AS bc
            ON bc.ProjectID = P.ProjectID;
```

To get the SUM of BC for each project.

I have made an assumption here that you are using SQL Server based on the use of square brackets for object names, and syntax in your previous questions. In which case I would use [`OUTER APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the latest actual spend row, giving a final query of:

```
SELECT  p.ProjectId, 
        p.Name, 
        p.Budget
        bc.BC,
        sp.ActualSpendAmount AS [Actual Spend],
        p.Budget - bc.BC + sp.ActualSpendAmount AS ETC
FROM    Projects p
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  bc.ProjectID, SUM(bc.BC) AS bc
            FROM    BC
            GROUP BY bc.ProjectID
        ) AS bc
            ON bc.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 sp.ActualSpendAmount
            FROM    [ActualSpend] AS sp
            WHERE   sp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
            ORDER BY sp.DateSpent DESC
        ) AS sp;
```

Comment: Thank you @GarethD and dnoeth for your response, I created the query without testing, since that was an extract from a larger piece.  But the actual question is, I need to use BC and ActualSpendAmount again for some computation in the same query.  If you see the last part of my query, the statement starting with "t.[Budget] - (SELECT BC + SELECT ActualSpendAmount)".  I dont want to repeat the two SELECTS for BC and ActualSpendAmount.  Is there a way to optimize the query.  All I think of storing every SELECT element to a local variable and use them for the computation. Is there a better way?

Comment: If my assumption that you are using SQL Server is correct, then this is exactly what the query I have posted does. If you need to calculate something using a correlated sub-query in the select, then move it to an `APPLY`, this means you can re-use the column as many times as you like. Even better, exactly as I have described, would be to use JOINs instead of a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected result your query is way too complicated (and will not run without errors).
Assuming your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregates:

```
SELECT p.ProjectId, p.NAME, p.Budget,
   BC.BC,
   act.ActualSpendAmount,
   p.Budget - (BC.BC + act.ActualSpendAmount)
FROM Projects AS p
LEFT JOIN
 ( -- sum of BC per project
   SELECT ProjectId, SUM(BC) AS BC
   FROM BC
   GROUP BY ProjectId
) AS BC
ON ProjectId=bc.ProjectId
JOIN 
 ( -- latest amount per project
   SELECT ProjectId, ActualSpendAmount,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId
            ORDER BY DateSpent DESC) AS rn
   FROM ActualSpend
 ) AS Act
ON Act.ProjectId=p.ProjectId
AND Act.rn = 1
```